# Complete isolation of javascript in the iframe from the same domain

Tags: javascript, iframe

Assume we have a window and an iframe with some javascript in it. The iframe sourcecode is defined directly in "srcdoc" attribute of the iframe.

Is it possible to somehow force the browser to behave like the iframe is loaded from another domain?

I mean I don't want the javascript in the iframe to be able to access the main window via "window.parent" or anything like that, because the iframe contents is not trusted. But the problem is that it's stored on the same domain and I even want to use the same request to load both the main window and the iframe contents (with that "srcdoc" attribute).

So is it possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could prepend the string:

```
"<script> parent = top = null; </script>"
```

To the srcdoc. That should prevent the rest of the code in the srcdoc form accessing the parent through `window.parent` and `window.top`.

I'm not sure if there are any other ways to access the parent of an iframe.

Comment: Great idea, thanks a lot! I'll have to care about "window.top" as well at least. Sorry, I can't vote up yet.

Comment: @AntonGromov You're welcome, and yes `window.top` is a good call. You can accept this answer if you want, by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Comment: this won't work (anymore), since window.top is a read-only property (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp)